# Has Israel, or anyone else, confirmed the Hamas claim that some hostages have been killed by Israel's bombing attack?

Tags: armed-conflict, terrorism, 2023-israel-hamas-war, collateral-damage

[Hamas says 60 hostages killed in Israeli airstrikes on Gaza Strip since Oct. 7](https://www.aa.com.tr/en/middle-east/hamas-says-60-hostages-killed-in-israeli-airstrikes-on-gaza-strip-since-oct-7/3044060):

> Hamas’s armed wing, Al-Qassam Brigades, said Saturday that 60 Israeli hostages have been killed in Israeli airstrikes on the Gaza Strip since Oct. 7. Spokesman Abu Obeida said after search operations, *"still there are 23 bodies (of hostages) lost under the rubble."* *"It seems we won't be able to reach them due to the ongoing brutal aggression by the occupation on Gaza,"* Abu Obeida added.

[Hamas armed wing says 'almost 50' Israeli hostages killed in raids](https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/news/international/world-news/hamas-armed-wing-says-almost-50-israeli-hostages-killed-in-raids/articleshow/104734310.cms):

> "(Ezzedine) Al-Qassam Brigades estimates that the number of Zionist prisoners who were killed in the Gaza Strip as a result of Zionist strikes and massacres has reached almost 50," the group said in a statement issued on its Telegram channel.

[Seven hostages killed in Gaza camp bombing says Hamas](https://www.thecitizen.co.tz/tanzania/news/international/seven-hostages-killed-in-gaza-camp-bombing-says-hamas-4420292):

> Seven hostages, including three foreign passport holders, were killed in Israel's bombing of Gaza's largest refugee camp, Hamas has said.

Israel's government, on the other hand, have once claimed that Hamas is slaughtering the hostages:

> The bodies of two Israeli hostages abducted by Hamas on October 7 were recovered Thursday by the Israel Defense Forces from the area of Shifa Hospital in the Gaza Strip, the military said. ... *“To our sorrow, Yehudit was murdered by the terrorists in the Gaza Strip. And we didn’t get to her in time,”* IDF Spokesman Rear Adm. Daniel Hagari said in his daily press briefing on Thursday evening. He did not specify when she was killed. - [*Military recovers bodies of two Israeli hostages in area of Gaza’s Shifa Hospital*](https://www.timesofisrael.com/idf-says-hostages-body-recovered-near-gazas-shifa-hospital-after-hamas-killed-her/)

(Both scenarios - of IDF accidentally or [intentionally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hannibal_Directive) killing the hostages while attempting to exterminate Hamas terrorists or Hamas deliberately killing the hostages when attacked - are highly likely).

I have 3 questions:

1. Has Hamas released the names and / or bodies of the hostages killed?
2. Has any independent agency corroborated the claims of Hamas that some hostages have indeed been killed in Israeli air raids? (Either by recovering hostage bodies from the rubble or by identification and autopsy).
3. Has Netanyahu's government released any statement on this or have been questioned on this issue by the opposition?

Comment: BTW, the claim of 60 dead appears to not be quite what Hamas said. Apparently they said 60 were missing with 23 dead according to them https://www.arabnews.com/node/2403311/middle-east

Comment: @Fizz Media reports are very conflicting. That is why I cited 3 different sources. There doesn't seem to be much coverage, or investigation, of these claims in western media.

Comment: There can't be, right now.

Comment: @Fizz Some news is now emerging that [this is indeed happening](https://www.haaretz.com/israel-news/2023-12-16/ty-article/.premium/hundreds-of-israelis-rally-in-tel-aviv-calling-for-immediate-release-of-hostages/0000018c-71c6-db38-a9fc-f9e608ee0000). The protests highlights why the government may not be inclined to investigate this matter urgently (or release the info publicly).